# Include arbitrary files in Android Studio for editing

Tags: android, android-studio, localization

Is it possible to include arbitrary files as part of a project in Android Studio?

I'm using a localisation system (twine) that builds my strings.xml file on the fly from a 'source' text file. This file is a non-android file (i.e it isn't a resource file, it isn't an asset, it isn't a java source file or gradle script etc).

However, I want this file to appear in my project in Android Studio so I can edit it. Is this even possible?

Comment: AFAIK, Android Studio ignores unrecognized directories. So, add a `dean/` directory somewhere in your project, put the files there, and see if Studio complains.

Comment: Indeed it won't complain, I have no issue in physically including the files. They don't appear in the project explorer in Android Studio, i.e the behaviour you describe is exactly what i'm seeing. I was wondering if I can create an exception and "tell" Android Studio to include a directory.

Comment: Switch to the "Project" view, instead of the "Android" view, for the project explorer, and they should show up.

Comment: You're right - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio ignores unrecognized directories, so you can go ahead and create arbitrary folders and files.

They don't appear in 'Android' tab of the project explorer, but they do show up i the 'Project Files' tab so you can edit them.